# When using web3j java library in a spring boot application, I am getting the below exception in the Web3j.build line. Any idea to fix this issue?

Tags: java, spring-boot

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: okhttp3.CipherSuite
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
> at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
> at org.web3j.protocol.http.HttpService.(HttpService.java:46)
> at com.relay.eth.ERC20TokenUtil.(ERC20TokenUtil.java:36)
> at com.relay.controller.open.APIController.getETHTokensBalance(APIController.java:398)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at

Using web3j java library in a spring boot application，start the springboot project to access this,

```
Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/{token}"))
```

And show error msg.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>4.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.web3j</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also add some crypto provider as a dependency to your project, just like it is stated in [web3j docs](https://github.com/web3j/web3j):

> It has five runtime dependencies:
>
> ...
>
> - Bouncy Castle (Spongy Castle on Android) for crypto
>
> ...

Answer (score 0):

i changed the pom dependency version

````
    ```<dependency>
        <groupId>org.web3j</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    ```
````

delete the okhttp3 dependency

and its wokrs